# Why did Belshazzar, King of Babylon name Daniel as the third ruler of his kingdom?

Tags: history, daniel

In Daniel 5:7, Belshazzar promised that whosoever read and interpreted the handwriting on the wall would be made the third ruler of his kingdom. This promise was fulfilled in verse 29 when Daniel was proclaimed the third ruler after reading and interpreting the said writing.  I find it difficult to understand why third ruler.  If Belshazzar was the king at that time and the Bible did not mention that he already had a second ruler,  why not make Daniel the second ruler instead?

Answer (score 5):

Nabonidus The King of Babylon (1st ruler) during the events of Daniel Ch. 5 had engaged Cyrus’ forces in battle but was Nabonidus took refuge in Borsippa (SSW of Babylon) and he left his Son, Belshazzar, to rule while he was engaging Cyrus, thus Belshazzar was acting as King Regent (2nd ruler), thus he could only offer Daniel 3rd place in rulership.

Comment: Thank you. It sure makes sense. But I'm not very clear yet.Who was Nabonidus? How is Belshazzar his son and the son of Nebuchadnezzar at the same time?

Comment: @Ere Oludiya  Nebuchadnezzar was the Grandfather of Belshazzar, thus he is called his son.  In eastern cultures, middle east, a grandson is just called a "son."

Comment: Okay.  That means one can rightly infer that Nabonidus was the son of Nebuchadnezzar.

Comment: Yes as they were a dynasty of Kings of Babylon.